# Как подключиться к интернет через iexplore?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

Делаю проект Windows Forms приложения на Visual Studio 2010. Программа работает со службой WCF опубликованной в интернете. Т.е. для нормальной работы этого приложения, нужно активное соединение с интернет.

Сейчас нормальная работа возможна, только, если есть прямое подключение компьютера к интернет. Обычно в программах бывают настройки подключения к интернет: *прокси-сервер*, *как у браузера*. Например, некоторые программы используют настройки iexplore, отображается диалог авторизации на сервере.

Как я могу реализовать тоже самое в своем приложении, настрйки подключение к интернет?
Не важно, на чем и какой проект приложения, лишь бы можно было добавлять ссылки на службы WCF и работать с ними.

**UPD**

Остался вопрос: как подключиться к интернет используя настройки iexplore?

Answer (score 5):

Добавить настройки прокси в приложение можно в конфиге, например так:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="server:port"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

UPD: Про диалог браузера ничего не могу сказать, но программно устанавливать прокси можно, как в этом примере с [МСДН](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx).

Comment: Нельзя ли программно устанавливать настройки? Пользователи могут быть разные.  
А где указывать пару логин-пароль?  
Пробовал еще

    <proxy usesystemdefault ="True"/> 
не помогло.

Comment: Пока есть вот это: [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx), [WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy.aspx).  
Делаю так  
        
    IWebProxy iproxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
    iproxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
данные прокси-сервера определяются правильно, но значение логин-пароль получить не удается.  Может как-то можно вывести диалог авторизации iexplore? Т.е., как авторизоваться?